# Firebase retrieve data and rewrite old values android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, overwrite

So I was retrieving old values from the Firebase database and tried to update the old values inside the `onDataChanged()` method but the activity seems to stop and goes back to the previous activity after I set the new values. When I checked the database it did add the new update but the activity crashes.

here is a snippet of the code:

```
        myRef = database.getReference("User").child(uid);
        databaseUser = database.getReference("User").child(uid);
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User ur = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                ur.setFitCoins(ur.getFitCoins()+coins);
                databaseUser.setValue(ur);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: try using databaseUser.updateValue(map);

Comment: it did update but it's still the same problem. The activity still crashes. @jitendrapurohit

Comment: show your crash logs

Comment: @RushabhShah there is nothing significant in the logs. There are no exceptions thrown as well

Comment: Without crashlog how can determine the cause!!

Comment: There's no crash imminent on the code you've provided. Please reproduce the problem and check if you get a log... Also post your User class.

Comment: Please update your question with the error. Every time it is a crash, there is an exception in the logcat. Please provide us that exception. Please also add your database structure and your model class.